# Should we allow rhetorical questions?

Tags: discussion

The question [Might more conlangers like writing in knots?](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/might-more-conlangers-like-writing-in-knots) is well-researched and interesting, but by the author's own admission isn't really a question that requires an answer. Do we want to allow this sort of rhetorical question on Constructed Languages SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that this question is ill-posed as it stands, but I also think that it is salvageable. It can be reformulated, e.g., in the following way:

Q: What are resources for conlangers designing a knot writing?

(Add a little of explanation to the question title, e.g., the first paragraph of the original question, and repeat the question.)

A: (Everything starting from "I made one such conscript")

Self-answering ones own question is 100% OK, as long as question and answer contribute something to this site. And more answers may come in.